# Pandas - GroupBy Apply (groupby.sum)

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to pass any function to a Pandas `DataFrame.GroupBy` object, so as to being able to apply any pre-defined function pointer to the `DataFrame` object. However, the behavior seems to change when I do.

```
group_test.groupby(groupby_indexes).sum()
```

Does not yield the same result as

```
group_test.groupby(groupby_indexes).apply(sum)
```

As the former solution adds columns of the GroupedBy variables, and does not properly sum the columns.
On the other hand, the following does not seem to be valid, as it yields an error, for both Python's `sum` and Panda's `DataFrame.sum`:

```
fun = Pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum
group_test.groupby(groupby_indexes).apply(fun)
```

An example, the output from the first option (desired and correct):

```
                        a   b   c
name             week           
Test             4      1   1   1
                 6      1   0   0
                 7      2   2   2
                 16     1   1   1
                 18     2   2   2
                 20     1   1   1
```

And the output from using the apply function (incorrect):

```
                        name       week    a    b   c
name         week                   
test         0      test test       0      2    1   1
             1      test            1      1    1   1
             2      test            2      1    0   0
             3.0    test            3      1    1   1
             4.0    test test       8      2    0   0
             5.0    test test test  15     3    1   1
             6.0    test            6      1    1   1
             7.0    test            7      1    0   0
             8.0    test test      16      2    0   0
             9.0    test           9       1    0   0
             11.0   test test      22      2    0   0
             12.0   test           12      1    1   1
             13.0   test           13      1    1   1
             15.0   test           15      1    0   0
             16.0   test           16      1    1   1
             17.0   test           17      1    1   1
             18.0   test           18      1    1   1
```

I found the solution, use `Pandas.Core.GroupBy.Agg`.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @IanS - You are right. Done. The behavior is quite strange. I think its because sum() is the regular python summing function, the optimal behavior should be to use Pandas' GroupBy.sum.

Comment: @IanS I have found the solution, using Pandas.Core.GroupBy.Agg.